# Aggregate Resource Allocation for a job in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Hadoop. When i run a job, i see the aggregate resource allocation for that job as 251248654 MB-seconds, 24462 vcore-seconds. However, when i find the details about the cluster, it shows there are 888 Vcores-total and 15.90 TB Memory-total. Can anyone tell me how this is related? what does MB-second and Vcore-seconds refer to for the job.

Is there any material online to know these? I tried surfing, dint get a proper answer

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
VCores-Total: Indicates the total number of VCores available in the cluster
Memory-Total: Indicates the total memory available in the cluster.
```

For e.g. I have a single node cluster, where, I have set memory requirements per container to be: 1228 MB (determined by config: `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`) and vCores per container to 1 vCore (determined by config: `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores`).

I have set: `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to 9830 MB. So, there can be totally 8 containers per node (9830 / 1228 = 8).

So, for my cluster:

```
VCores-Total = 1 (node) * 8 (containers) * 1 (vCore per container) = 8 
Memory-Total = 1 (node) * 8 (containers) * 1228 MB (memory per container) = 9824 MB = 9.59375 GB = 9.6 GB
```

The figure below, shows my cluster metrics:
[image]

Now let's see **"MB-seconds"** and **"vcore-seconds"**.
As per the description in the code (ApplicationResourceUsageReport.java):

**MB-seconds**: The aggregated amount of memory (in megabytes) the application has allocated times the number of seconds the application has been running.

**vcore-seconds**: The aggregated number of vcores that the application has allocated times the number of seconds the application has been running.

The description is self-explanatory (remember the keyword: Aggregated).

Let me explain this with an example.
I ran a DistCp job (which spawned 25 containers), for which I got the following:

```
Aggregate Resource Allocation: 10361661 MB-seconds, 8424 vcore-seconds
```

Now, let's do some rough calculation on how much time each container took:

```
For memory:
10361661 MB-seconds = 10361661 / 25 (containers) / 1228 MB (memory per container) = 337.51 seconds = 5.62 minutes

For CPU
8424 vcore-seconds = 8424 / 25 (containers) / 1 (vCore per container) = 336.96 seconds = 5.616 minutes
```

This indicates on an average, each container took 5.62 minutes to execute.

I hope this makes it clear. You can execute a job and confirm it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Manjunath. It was very precise and very well explained.

Comment: how would i be able to get the number of containers present in each node and vcores assigned per container??  our cluster has a total of 74 nodes. I could get those details from the cluster details in http://host:8088/cluster link. But could not find other details

Comment: You could get the number of containers for each node using host:8080/cluster/nodes/ . Here it shows the details for each node

Comment: if my cluster is big, the number of containers assigned per job varies right??? i am not sure how MB-seconds and Vcore-seconds are calculated. is it memory allocated multiplied by duration?? if so, i am not able to get the correct value. My job: 195440 MB-seconds, 19 vcore-seconds and Duration it ran: 18 sec

Comment: Number of containers depends on the requirements of your job. For e.g for a mapreduce job, it depends on the number of mappers and reducers. These are aggregated numbers. In short you can say the these are the average time taken by each container multiplied by number of containers multiplied by (VC-Core per container or Memory per container). I am getting perfect numbers.

Comment: Containers may change across the executions and the size of the containers also may change, so unless every container has same memory and vcores this post is not correct.

Comment: Love your answer! :)