# Get the memory, CPU and disk usage for Yarn application

Tags: memory, mapreduce, cpu-usage, hadoop-yarn

I want to ask after I've run a Yarn application, how can I get the total memory and CPU usage of that application.

I used to use the resource manager UI to get all the information.
But aside from getting this information from the UI, are there any
commands that I can use to achieve the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `yarn application -status` command, you can get the `Aggregate Resource Allocation` for an application.

For e.g. when I type `yarn application -status application_1452267331813_0009` (for one of my completed applications), one of the rows returned is:

```
Aggregate Resource Allocation : 46641 MB-seconds, 37 vcore-seconds
```

This gives an aggregate memory and CPU allocations in seconds. You can check this answer: [Aggregate Resource Allocation for a job in YARN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866888/aggregate-resource-allocation-for-a-job-in-yarn/33868015#33868015), to understand the meaning of this output.

Apart from this, as of now, there are no other memory or CPU related metrics exposed through CLI.

Answer (score 2):

The command `yarn top` gives application level resource utilization and elapsed run time.

See this thread for a way to pipe the output to a file https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782200/12693167

--help info:

> usage: yarn top
>
> -cols      Number of columns on the terminal
>
> -delay     The refresh delay(in seconds), default is 3 seconds
>
> -help           Print usage; for help while the tool is running press 'h' + Enter
>
> -queues    Comma separated list of queues to restrict applications
>
> -rows      Number of rows on the terminal
>
> -types     Comma separated list of types to restrict applications, case sensitive(though the display is lower case)
>
> -users     Comma separated list of users to restrict applications
>
> 'yarn top' is a tool to help cluster administrators understand cluster usage better.
>   Some notes about the implementation:
>
> 1. Fetching information for all the apps is an expensive call for the RM.
>       To prevent a performance degradation, the results are cached for 5 seconds,
>       irrespective of the delay value. Information about the NodeManager(s) and queue
>       utilization stats are fetched at the specified delay interval. Once we have a
>       better understanding of the performance impact, this might change.
> 2. Since the tool is implemented in Java, you must hit Enter for key presses to
>       be processed.