# How to exit the interactive mode for yarn top command from within the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, linux-mint

I have a bash script which is on serverA. This script will ssh to serverB and runs yarn top command, pulls the metrics and put into the file(test.txt) on serverA. Below is the command which I am using:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i <key> username@hostname "yarn top" | head -5 | grep -w 'Applications' | awk '{print "Pending_apps" "\t" $7}' >> test.txt
```

So here the problem is that after my script runs above command it goes into interactive mode and it only exits when I give Ctrl+C or quit signal/command manually.

Is there any way through which after running the above command and redirecting the output to test.txt the script should move to the next command. That is after running the above command on the command prompt it should redirect output to a test.txt file and then should return back to command prompt/terminal

Answer (score 2):

You can try to emulate the console by piping the output of `echo` like this:

```
(sleep $SLEEP_TIME; echo -e "q\n\n") | yarn top > yarn-top.log
```

It means: "run yarn top, and in parallel, wait `SLEEP_TIME` and then output q and two new lines".

As far as `SLEEP_TIME` is less than the default refresh delay on `yarn top` (3 seconds by default), you will get one screen update in `yarn-top.log`. If you set `SLEEP_TIME` greater than the refresh delay, you will get as many updates as it has time to run during the `SLEEP_TIME`.

You need `echo -e` to escape the newline chars. You need them because `yarn top` is implemented in java. See `yarn top --help`:

> 2. Since the tool is implemented in Java, you must hit Enter for key presses to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Classic `top` can be run in non-interactive mode by `top -n 1` Unfortunately I can't find documentation for `yarn top`

or you can try run command in background (`&`), save its pid, wait for data and kill it

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i <key> username@hostname "yarn top" | head -5 | grep -w 'Applications' | awk '{print "Pending_apps" "\t" $7}' >> test.txt & PID=$!; sleep 1; kill -s SIGINT $PID
```

hopefully ssh transfer SIGINT successfuly

Comment: while running the command in background still I am unable to get to command prompt. Could you please let me know how could I use above ssh command to send output to test.txt and return back to the command prompt.